# Hyper-V Virtual Switches: Generic error

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I am using Windows Server 2019 and have Hyper-V enabled.
The first days everything worked without any problems until I decided to add a domain controller to the server.

From this moment on I was no longer able to start the VMs. Error message: "The status of VMNAME could not be changed".
Also creating new VMs was no longer possible. Error message: "Error when adding resources to VMNAME".

Then I found out that I can't select a virtual switch when creating or editing a VM.

The attempt to create a new one also fails. As soon as I want to start the Virtual Switch Manager, I get the error message: "Error during operation on computer COMPUTERNAME: Generic error".
I also no longer have a Hyper-V network adapter.

So I think that everything depends on this network problem.
I have reinstalled Hyper-V several times and also reset all network adapters with the command: "netcfg -d".
Also via Powershell it is impossible for me to create a virtual switch.

How can I fix this problem or reset Hyper-V completely?
Unfortunately a new installation is out of the question.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify, you added the domain controller role to the Hyper-V host, making your Hyper-V server a domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make your Hyper-V host also be a domain controller.

First of all, a domain controller will automatically disable write-back caching
on the volumes on which Active Directory data is stored.
This will impact the performance of your host negatively by a hefty amount
(I have seen 30% mentioned but no benchmarks).

Second, you are on unexplored grounds:

- The standard recommendation for Hyper-V is to run nothing at all except Hyper-V
  on the host.
- The standard recommendation for DCs is to run nothing at all on a DC except AD.

Microsoft itself does not support this configuration, so anything can happen.
Because of that, no professional ever sets up such a configuration,
so no documentation exists on solving problems on it, and you are unlikely
to find any help.

My recommendation: It is OK to have the DC in a VM, and this is the recommended
approach. (There was reason in previous versions of Windows against this,
but it no longer applies today.)

More reading:

- [7 Reasons not to Make Hyper-V a Domain Controller](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/reasons-not-to-make-hyper-v-a-domain-controller/)
- [Hyper-V: Revisiting the Chicken and the Egg Paradox](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/02/27/hyper-v-chicken-and-egg.aspx)